# Can't update conda - All packages up to date

Tags: conda, mamba

OS: Windows 10

I can't update conda anymore.

I get this warning:

```
==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
    current version: 23.11.0
    latest version: 24.1.2
```

But when running the conda update command

```
conda update -n base -c conda-forge conda
```

Nothing happens, all packages are up to date

```
# All requested packages already installed.
```

This happens with classic solver and libmaba solver.

I then tried

```
conda install conda=24.1.2
```

with libmamba solver and I get a huge list of why it can't be done but I can't figure out what it actually means or what I should do. See the output add end of the question.

I then tried to remove conda-libmamba-solver with classic solver to maybe resolve the conflict. But that wanted to remove conda itself so I cancelled as I expected this would trash the install completely.

Therefore how can I update conda to newest version?

libmamba solver output:

```
Could not solve for environment specs
The following packages are incompatible
├─ conda-libmamba-solver is installable with the potential options
│  ├─ conda-libmamba-solver 24.1.0 would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy [>=1.5.6 |>=1.5.6,<2.0a0 ] with the potential options
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.5.6, which can be installed;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy [1.0.0|1.1.0|...|1.5.6] would require
│  │     │  └─ python >=3.11,<3.12.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy [1.5.1|1.5.2|...|1.5.6] would require
│  │     │  └─ python >=3.12,<3.13.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy [0.22.0|0.22.1|...|1.5.6] would require
│  │     │  └─ python >=3.8,<3.9.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy [0.22.0|0.22.1|...|1.5.6] would require
│  │     │  └─ python >=3.9,<3.10.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  │     └─ libmambapy 1.5.6 would require
│  │        └─ libmamba 1.5.6 h99b1521_0, which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel);
│  ├─ conda-libmamba-solver [22.3.0|22.3.1] would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy 0.22.*  with the potential options
│  │     ├─ libmambapy [0.22.0|0.22.1|...|1.5.6], which can be installed (as previously explained);
│  │     ├─ libmambapy [0.22.0|0.22.1|...|1.5.6], which can be installed (as previously explained);
│  │     ├─ libmambapy [0.22.0|0.22.1|...|1.3.1] would require
│  │     │  └─ python >=3.7,<3.8.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 0.22.0 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 0.22.1 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 0.22.1 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     └─ libmambapy 0.22.1, which can be installed;
│  ├─ conda-libmamba-solver [22.6.0|22.8.1] would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy >=0.23  with the potential options
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.5.6, which can be installed;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy [1.0.0|1.1.0|...|1.5.6], which can be installed (as previously explained);
│  │     ├─ libmambapy [1.5.1|1.5.2|...|1.5.6], which can be installed (as previously explained);
│  │     ├─ libmambapy [0.22.0|0.22.1|...|1.5.6], which can be installed (as previously explained);
│  │     ├─ libmambapy [0.22.0|0.22.1|...|1.5.6], which can be installed (as previously explained);
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.5.6, which cannot be installed (as previously explained);
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.5.1 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.5.1 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.5.1 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.5.2 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.5.2 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy [1.5.3|1.5.4|1.5.5], which can be installed;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.5.1, which can be installed;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.4.1 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.4.2 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.4.4 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.4.4 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.4.5 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.4.6 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.4.7 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy [1.4.1|1.4.8], which can be installed;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.4.9 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.5.0 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.5.0 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.0.0 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.0.0 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.0.0 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.0.0 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.0.0 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy [1.0.0|1.3.1], which can be installed;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.1.0 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.1.0 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.1.0 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.1.0 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.2.0 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.2.0 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.3.0 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.3.0 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.3.1 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.3.1 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.4.0 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy [0.22.0|0.22.1|...|1.3.1], which can be installed (as previously explained);
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 0.23.0 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 0.23.1 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 0.23.3 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 0.24.0 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 0.25.0 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 0.25.0 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 0.26.0 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 0.27.0 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 0.23.1 would require
│  │     │  └─ libmamba 0.23.1 habe1e26_0, which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel);
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 0.23.3 would require
│  │     │  └─ libmamba 0.23.3 habe1e26_0, which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel);
│  │     └─ libmambapy 0.24.0, which can be installed;
│  ├─ conda-libmamba-solver [22.12.0|23.1.0] would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy >=1.0.0  with the potential options
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.5.6, which can be installed;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy [1.0.0|1.1.0|...|1.5.6], which can be installed (as previously explained);
│  │     ├─ libmambapy [1.5.1|1.5.2|...|1.5.6], which can be installed (as previously explained);
│  │     ├─ libmambapy [0.22.0|0.22.1|...|1.5.6], which can be installed (as previously explained);
│  │     ├─ libmambapy [0.22.0|0.22.1|...|1.5.6], which can be installed (as previously explained);
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.5.6, which cannot be installed (as previously explained);
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.5.1 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.5.1 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.5.1 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.5.2 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.5.2 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy [1.5.3|1.5.4|1.5.5], which can be installed;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.5.1, which can be installed;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.4.1 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.4.2 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.4.4 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.4.4 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.4.5 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.4.6 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.4.7 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy [1.4.1|1.4.8], which can be installed;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.4.9 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.5.0 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.5.0 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.0.0 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.0.0 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.0.0 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.0.0 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.0.0 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy [1.0.0|1.3.1], which can be installed;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.1.0 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.1.0 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.1.0 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.1.0 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.2.0 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.2.0 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.3.0 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.3.0 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.3.1 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.3.1 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.4.0 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     └─ libmambapy [0.22.0|0.22.1|...|1.3.1], which can be installed (as previously explained);
│  ├─ conda-libmamba-solver [23.11.0|23.11.1|23.12.0] would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy >=1.5.3  with the potential options
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.5.6, which can be installed;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy [1.0.0|1.1.0|...|1.5.6], which can be installed (as previously explained);
│  │     ├─ libmambapy [1.5.1|1.5.2|...|1.5.6], which can be installed (as previously explained);
│  │     ├─ libmambapy [0.22.0|0.22.1|...|1.5.6], which can be installed (as previously explained);
│  │     ├─ libmambapy [0.22.0|0.22.1|...|1.5.6], which can be installed (as previously explained);
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.5.6, which cannot be installed (as previously explained);
│  │     └─ libmambapy [1.5.3|1.5.4|1.5.5], which can be installed;
│  ├─ conda-libmamba-solver [23.3.0|23.5.0|23.7.0] would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy >=1.4.1  with the potential options
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.5.6, which can be installed;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy [1.0.0|1.1.0|...|1.5.6], which can be installed (as previously explained);
│  │     ├─ libmambapy [1.5.1|1.5.2|...|1.5.6], which can be installed (as previously explained);
│  │     ├─ libmambapy [0.22.0|0.22.1|...|1.5.6], which can be installed (as previously explained);
│  │     ├─ libmambapy [0.22.0|0.22.1|...|1.5.6], which can be installed (as previously explained);
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.5.6, which cannot be installed (as previously explained);
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.5.1 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.5.1 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.5.1 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.5.2 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.5.2 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy [1.5.3|1.5.4|1.5.5], which can be installed;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.5.1, which can be installed;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.4.1 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.4.2 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.4.4 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.4.4 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.4.5 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.4.6 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.4.7 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy [1.4.1|1.4.8], which can be installed;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.4.9 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.5.0 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     └─ libmambapy 1.5.0 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ conda-libmamba-solver [23.9.0|23.9.1|23.9.2|23.9.3] would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy >=1.5.1  with the potential options
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.5.6, which can be installed;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy [1.0.0|1.1.0|...|1.5.6], which can be installed (as previously explained);
│  │     ├─ libmambapy [1.5.1|1.5.2|...|1.5.6], which can be installed (as previously explained);
│  │     ├─ libmambapy [0.22.0|0.22.1|...|1.5.6], which can be installed (as previously explained);
│  │     ├─ libmambapy [0.22.0|0.22.1|...|1.5.6], which can be installed (as previously explained);
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.5.6, which cannot be installed (as previously explained);
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.5.1 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.5.1 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.5.1 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.5.2 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy 1.5.2 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     ├─ libmambapy [1.5.3|1.5.4|1.5.5], which can be installed;
│  │     └─ libmambapy 1.5.1, which can be installed;
│  ├─ conda-libmamba-solver [22.12.0|22.8.1|23.1.0] would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.7,<3.8.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  ├─ conda-libmamba-solver [22.12.0|22.8.1|...|23.9.3] would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.8,<3.9.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  ├─ conda-libmamba-solver [22.12.0|22.8.1|...|23.9.3] would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.9,<3.10.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  └─ conda-libmamba-solver [23.1.0|23.11.0|...|23.9.3] would require
│     └─ python >=3.11,<3.12.0a0 , which can be installed;
├─ conda 24.1.2**  is installable with the potential options
│  ├─ conda 24.1.2 would require
│  │  └─ conda-libmamba-solver >=23.11.0 , which can be installed (as previously explained);
│  ├─ conda [23.10.0|23.11.0|23.9.0|24.1.2] would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.11,<3.12.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  ├─ conda [23.10.0|23.11.0|23.9.0|24.1.2] would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.12,<3.13.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  ├─ conda [23.10.0|23.11.0|23.9.0|24.1.2] would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.8,<3.9.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  └─ conda [23.10.0|23.11.0|23.9.0|24.1.2] would require
│     └─ python >=3.9,<3.10.0a0 , which can be installed;
├─ mamba is installable with the potential options
│  ├─ mamba 0.18.1 would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy 0.18.1 py310hcc243ed_1, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ mamba [1.5.4|1.5.5|1.5.6] would require
│  │  └─ conda >=23.11,<23.12  with the potential options
│  │     ├─ conda [23.10.0|23.11.0|23.9.0|24.1.2], which can be installed (as previously explained);
│  │     ├─ conda [23.10.0|23.11.0|23.9.0|24.1.2], which can be installed (as previously explained);
│  │     ├─ conda [23.10.0|23.11.0|23.9.0|24.1.2], which can be installed (as previously explained);
│  │     ├─ conda [23.10.0|23.11.0|23.9.0|24.1.2], which can be installed (as previously explained);
│  │     └─ conda 23.11.0 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ mamba [0.0.7|0.1.0|...|0.9.2] would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.6,<3.7.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  ├─ mamba [0.0.7|0.1.0|...|0.9.2] would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.7,<3.8.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  ├─ mamba [0.1.2|0.10.0|...|1.5.6] would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.8,<3.9.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  ├─ mamba [0.10.0|0.11.1|...|1.5.6] would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.9,<3.10.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  ├─ mamba 0.18.2 would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy 0.18.2 py310hcc243ed_0, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ mamba 0.19.0 would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy 0.19.0 py310hcc243ed_0, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ mamba 0.19.1 would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy 0.19.1 py310hcc243ed_0, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ mamba 0.20.0 would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy 0.20.0 py310hcc243ed_0, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ mamba 0.21.0 would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy 0.21.0 py310hcc243ed_0, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ mamba 0.21.1 would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy 0.21.1 py310hcc243ed_0, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ mamba 0.21.2 would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy 0.21.2 py310hcc243ed_0, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ mamba 0.22.0 would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy 0.22.0 py310hcc243ed_0, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ mamba 0.22.1 would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy 0.22.1 py310hcc243ed_0, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ mamba 0.22.1 would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy 0.22.1 py310hd80b381_1, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ mamba 0.23.0 would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy 0.23.0 py310hd80b381_1, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ mamba 0.23.1 would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy 0.23.1 py310hd80b381_1, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ mamba 0.23.3 would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy 0.23.3 py310hd80b381_1, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ mamba 0.24.0 would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy 0.24.0 py310hd80b381_1, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ mamba 0.25.0 would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy 0.25.0 py310hd80b381_1, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ mamba 0.25.0 would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy 0.25.0 py310hd80b381_2, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ mamba 0.26.0 would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy 0.26.0 py310heb5fb4d_0, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ mamba 0.27.0 would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy 0.27.0 py310heb5fb4d_0, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ mamba 1.0.0 would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy 1.0.0 py310h10c372a_0, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ mamba 1.0.0 would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy 1.0.0 py310h10c372a_1, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ mamba 1.0.0 would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy 1.0.0 py310h10c372a_2, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ mamba 1.0.0 would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy 1.0.0 py310he5ed166_1, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ mamba 1.0.0 would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy 1.0.0 py310he5ed166_2, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ mamba [1.0.0|1.1.0|...|1.5.6] would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.11,<3.12.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  ├─ mamba 1.1.0 would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy 1.1.0 py310h954024b_2, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ mamba 1.1.0 would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy 1.1.0 py310h954024b_3, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ mamba 1.1.0 would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy 1.1.0 py310h3fe4c2e_2, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ mamba 1.1.0 would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy 1.1.0 py310h3fe4c2e_3, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ mamba 1.2.0 would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy 1.2.0 py310h954024b_0, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ mamba 1.2.0 would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy 1.2.0 py310h3fe4c2e_0, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ mamba 1.3.0 would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy 1.3.0 py310h3fe4c2e_0, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ mamba 1.3.0 would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy 1.3.0 py310h3fe4c2e_1, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ mamba 1.3.1 would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy 1.3.1 py310h3fe4c2e_1, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ mamba 1.3.1 would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy 1.3.1 py310h3fe4c2e_2, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ mamba 1.4.0 would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy 1.4.0 py310h3fe4c2e_0, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ mamba 1.4.1 would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy 1.4.1 py310h3fe4c2e_0, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ mamba 1.4.2 would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy 1.4.2 py310h3fe4c2e_0, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ mamba 1.4.4 would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy 1.4.4 py310h3fe4c2e_0, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ mamba 1.4.4 would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy 1.4.4 py310h3fe4c2e_1, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ mamba 1.4.5 would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy 1.4.5 py310h3fe4c2e_0, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ mamba 1.4.6 would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy 1.4.6 py310h3fe4c2e_0, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ mamba 1.4.7 would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy 1.4.7 py310h3fe4c2e_0, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ mamba 1.4.9 would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy 1.4.9 py310h3fe4c2e_0, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ mamba 1.5.0 would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy 1.5.0 py310h3fe4c2e_0, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ mamba 1.5.0 would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy 1.5.0 py310h04f2035_1, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ mamba 1.5.1 would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy 1.5.1 py310h04f2035_0, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ mamba 1.5.1 would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy 1.5.1 py310h04f2035_1, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ mamba 1.5.1 would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy 1.5.1 py310h04f2035_2, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ mamba 1.5.2 would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy 1.5.2 py310h04f2035_0, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ mamba 1.5.2 would require
│  │  └─ libmambapy 1.5.2 py310h04f2035_1, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ mamba [1.5.2|1.5.3|1.5.4|1.5.5|1.5.6] would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.12,<3.13.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  └─ mamba 1.5.3 would require
│     └─ conda >=23.9,<23.11.0  with the potential options
│        ├─ conda [23.10.0|23.11.0|23.9.0|24.1.2], which can be installed (as previously explained);
│        ├─ conda [23.10.0|23.11.0|23.9.0|24.1.2], which can be installed (as previously explained);
│        ├─ conda [23.10.0|23.11.0|23.9.0|24.1.2], which can be installed (as previously explained);
│        ├─ conda [23.10.0|23.11.0|23.9.0|24.1.2], which can be installed (as previously explained);
│        └─ conda [23.10.0|23.9.0] conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
└─ pin-1 is not installable because it requires
   └─ python 3.10.* , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported.
```

Comment: Mamba is currently incompatible with the latest Conda version (24.1). Track the [repo Issue](https://github.com/conda-forge/mamba-feedstock/issues/210) for status. Otherwise, either sit tight - nothing catastrophic happens by not updating immediately - or remove `mamba`.